# How to parse content with HTML::Parser

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing, www-mechanize

I have web page with different URL's.
I created script to get URL's from page through `WWW::Mechanize` Perl module.

```
my @links = $mech->find_all_links( text_regex => qr/client_update/i  );
   foreach (@links) {
        push (@new_arr, $_->url() ,"\n");
      }
```

Now I should get only grey color URL's, check tag-name with attribute and value:

```
<td class="highlight-grey" data-highlight-colour="**grey**"><a href="http://cache.download.it/download/soker/client_update.php">cache.download.it/download/soker/client_update.php</a></td>
```

BTW, I don't have possibility to install modules like "HTML::TreeBuilder" for my task.

Comment: so what exactly happens for what input and what would you like to happen? Also, note that find_all_links returns WWW::Mechanize::Link objects, see http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Efind_all_links%28_..._%29

Comment: yes, I got  all links (with grey, green and red colors).

I would like to get only grey links. How I can do it ?

Comment: Ok, got the question now. Well, the links are within the td, so using find_all_links, the information you need to do that is lost the way I see it. You have to first get all the right td's then get all links contained within. I have always used Mechanize + TreeBuilder, so not sure how to use HTML::Parser to that effect, so I suggest re-wording your question so someone who knows it better can see more clearly what you want. Also, consider installing TreeBuilder locally with local::lib.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828

Comment: Have found solution:

Answer (score 0):

```
    Have found solution:



 my $webpage = {
        username    =>  'xx',
        password    =>  'xx',
        url         =>  'xx',
        form_name   =>  'loginform',
        regex       =>  qr/data-highlight-colour="grey"><a\s+href="/xsm,
    };

    my @links = $mech->find_all_links(text_regex => qr/client_update_urls/i);
        my @raw_content = $mech->response()->content();

        my @prod_urls;
        foreach my $line (@raw_content) {
            foreach my $link (@links) {
                my $url = $link->url();
                if ($line !~ /$webpage->{regex}$url/xsm) {
                    push @prod_urls, $url;
                }
            }
        }

        for (@prod_urls) {print "$_\n"}
```